# Functions on substrings in regex

Tags: regex

Is there a way to use functions on substrings in regex?

examples:

### `|` (or)

```
19[89|90]
```

Should match: `1989`, `1990`

Should not match `1980`, `199`

### `{n}` (counter)

```
ab{2}
```

Should match `abab`

Should not match `ab`, `ab`

### `?`, `+`, `*` (Quantifiers)

```
abc+
```

should match `abcabc`

Sould not match `abccabc`

Comment: Yes, they are all possible.  Have you tried them?  Try using http://www.regex101.com to test them all out.

Comment: Are you asking if a function can be used on the result of what you posted? If you're using pen and paper then for sure. What language do you want to use? If you mean is this syntax implemented then yes, it looks like you copy pasted a manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to use some kind of grouping to use quantifiers on the whole substring. Alternation (`|`) does not need to group the alternatives.

```
 substring1|substring2
 (substring){2}
 (substring)?
 (substring)+
 (substring)*
 (substring1|substring2)+
```

More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Comment: So simple. Thanks!